# Why does HttpListener "conflict with an existing registration" when listening to a Strong Wildcard (http://+:port) http.sys/urlacl binding?

Tags: c#, windows, http, owin, httplistener

Imagine that an elevated user (eg. installer) configures a URL reservation:

```
 netsh http add urlacl url="https://+:8105/" user="SVCACCOUNT" listen=yes
```

Now when Owin started (running under SVCACCOUNT), the following error results:

```
System.Net.HttpListenerException: Failed to listen on prefix 'http://+:8105/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener.Start(..)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinServerFactory.Create(..)
...
at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext context)
```

And the Owin 'entry' point:

```
WebApp.Start("http://+:8105", ..)
```

---

During creation of the question, I discovered that a registration of `http://*:8105`  and an Owin / HttpListener URL of the same "worked".

- **What prevents HttpListener (and thus Owin) from *using* the registrations previously taken with a Strong Wildcard?**
- **Why does using `*` (a "weak wildcard") in both registration and binding allow a listener to start?** (Using a "strong wildcard" is throwing the error above; removing the registration entirely will cause the listener to fail with an "Access is denied" due to limited account access.)

*Where is this documented,* and what 'ramifications' does the fix of switching from a strong to weak wildcard have? And why does this fix even work? From the many times a related question has been asked (often without a good answer), it appears that `+` "probably worked" in the past and/or on different systems or configurations: what changed?

(I've found scattered documentation on http.sys configuration, such as [Host-Specifier Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364698(v=vs.85).aspx) although still no clear explanation for the 'conflicting registration'.)

---

If the registrations are deleted per [System.Net.HttpListenerException: Failed to listen on prefix 'http://localhost:8080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714055/system-net-httplistenerexception-failed-to-listen-on-prefix-http-localhost8) the Owin service starts successfully. However I believe that this then requires higher elevations to listen to the ports.

This is *not* a duplicate of "[Owin self-host - Failed to listen on prefix 'http://localhost:12345/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406223/owin-self-host-failed-to-listen-on-prefix-http-localhost12345-because-it)" because the question only arises when there *is* a URL reservation defined: also, there is no other process listening, as confirmed via netstat.

Questions like [Self hosted OWIN and urlacl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642651/self-hosted-owin-and-urlacl?rq=1) make me believe it's either a permission issue or something trivial.. eg., how does `http://+:port` differ from `http://*:port`? (And no, using 'EVERYONE' for the urlacl does not resolve the issue.)

The comment in "[Running self-hosted OWIN Web API under non-admin account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976425/running-self-hosted-owin-web-api-under-non-admin-account)" might be relevant - pertains to `+` vs `*` .. and a general lack of clarification.

Answer (score 1):

`- What prevents HttpListener (and thus Owin) from using the registrations previously taken with a Strong Wildcard?`

Maybe the problem was you are registering `HTTPS` protocol:

```
netsh http add urlacl url="https://+:8105/" user="SVCACCOUNT" listen=yes
```

And then you are using the `HTTP` protocol in the code:

```
WebApp.Start("http://+:8105", ..)
```

```
-Why does using * (a "weak wildcard") in both registration and binding allow a listener to start?
```

The difference between `*` and `+` wildcards are the `*` include the void element and the `+` force to exist at least 1 character. I don't known the execution difference, but is probably a tiny almost imperceptible.